# Story with Female Partial-Vampire Protagonist

Tags: story-identification, vampire

I'm trying to determine the title (and author) of a short-story or possibly novel that I read during the late 90's or early 2000's.

The general premise of the story is a young woman, seduced by a vampire, is left for dead (I believe she was tossed out of a car) after having been feed on. In the story's mythology, the victim must die prior to being "turned". The protagonist does not die and instead awakes to find that she is sharing her body with a consciousness of the demon that would have controlled her body had she completely turned. The young lady is upset by this turn of events and proceeds to hunt and kill other vampires.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty sure the novel you're looking for is *Sunglasses After Dark* by Nancy A. Collins. The main character, Sonja Blue, is attacked by a vampire, thrown out of a car. She is left for dead, but because she doesn't die, she shares her consciousness with the demon who would have taken over her body. She hunts other vampires and kills them, seeking to find the vampire who turned her. *Midnight Blue* is a collection of stories about Sonja Blue.

[image]
[image]